# How to change the file name during the download process in Jhipster (java + angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

This is the code that seems to open it from the controller:

```js
 openFile(contentType, field) {
    return this.dataUtils.openFile(contentType, field);
  }
```

and in the HTML this is used while passing in data from an object returned from the service like so:

```html
 <button type="submit" (click)="openFile(dataCleansing.fileContentType, dataCleansing.uploadedFileContent)"
                class=" btn
                btn-info viewTheme">
                <fa-icon [icon]="'download'"></fa-icon>
                </fa-icon>&nbsp;<span> Open/View File</span>
            </button>
```

My goal is that I download the file and when it is downloaded it carries the filename and not as `download(1)` or `download(2)` and in windows it uses some random ids (not related to the fileID).  I would like it so that the downloaded file can be easily located by the user.  I tried add header content-filename.  But I could not parse it and set it.  Looks like Jhipsters built in service called `data-utils.service.ts` is in control of download file functionality.  which looks like this inside the node modules:

```js
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
/**
 * An utility service for data.
 */
export declare class JhiDataUtils {
    constructor();
    /**
     * Method to abbreviate the text given
     */
    abbreviate(text: string, append?: string): string;
    /**
     * Method to find the byte size of the string provides
     */
    byteSize(base64String: string): string;
    /**
     * Method to open file
     */
    openFile(contentType: string, data: string): void;
    /**
     * Method to convert the file to base64
     */
    toBase64(file: File, cb: Function): void;
    /**
     * Method to clear the input
     */
    clearInputImage(entity: any, elementRef: ElementRef, field: string, fieldContentType: string, idInput: string): void;
    /**
     * Sets the base 64 data & file type of the 1st file on the event (event.target.files[0]) in the passed entity object
     * and returns a promise.
     *
     * @param event the object containing the file (at event.target.files[0])
     * @param entity the object to set the file's 'base 64 data' and 'file type' on
     * @param field the field name to set the file's 'base 64 data' on
     * @param isImage boolean representing if the file represented by the event is an image
     * @returns a promise that resolves to the modified entity if operation is successful, otherwise rejects with an error message
     */
    setFileData(event: any, entity: any, field: string, isImage: boolean): Promise<any>;
    /**
     * Method to download file
     */
    downloadFile(contentType: string, data: string, fileName: string): void;
    private endsWith;
    private paddingSize;
    private size;
    private formatAsBytes;
}
```

Any directions and tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's to general as an answer, but it's at least part of "any directions and tips" and you might find some other hints including a way to name your files for download here: https://blog.ippon.tech/create-a-simple-file-storage-through-database-with-jhipster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you really want is to download files not open them. `JhiDataUtils` has a method specifically for this:

```
downloadFile(contentType: string, data: string, fileName: string): void;
```

Try using that method instead of `openFile()`, something like this in the HTML:

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info viewTheme" 
    (click)="downloadFile(dataCleansing.fileContentType, dataCleansing.uploadedFileContent)">
    <fa-icon [icon]="'download'"></fa-icon> Download File
</button>
```

You can then put whatever filename you want in the controller:

```or-tag-here
  downloadFile(contentType: string, field: string) {
    const filename = 'report_' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm');
    this.dataUtils.downloadFile(contentType, field, filename);
  }
```

In any case, the correct header to set the name of a file attachment would be:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=custom_name.pdf;
```

I did not test this code.

Comment: Thank you! @vicpermir.   Using `downloadFile(contentType: string, data: string, fileName: string): void;` did it for me.